# How to see the output after getting the data in web scraping?

Tags: python, html, data-visualization

I typed some code to get some data from a site (scraping) and I got the result I want (results are just numbers).
the question is, how can I show results as an output on my website? I am using python and HTML in Vs Code. Here is the **scraping** code:

```
   import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

getpage= requests.get('https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/austria/')
getpage_soup= BeautifulSoup(getpage.text, 'html.parser')
Get_Total_Deaths_Recoverd_Cases= getpage_soup.findAll('div', {'class':'maincounter-number'})

for para in Get_Total_Deaths_Recoverd_Cases:
    print (para.text)




Get_Active_And_Closed= BeautifulSoup(getpage.text, 'html.parser')
All_Numbers2= Get_Active_And_Closed.findAll('div', {'class':'number-table-main'})

for para2 in All_Numbers2:
    print (para2.text)
```

and these are the results that I want to show on the website:

> 

577,007

9,687

535,798

31,522
545,485

Comment: What framework does your web site use?  If you know how to write HTML in response to a request, then you just substitute this code with appropriate formatting.

Comment: have a look at D3, how do you want to show these numbers

Comment: You can use Flask or Django to show the output on the website.

Comment: You can also theoretically write to an html file but like literally You have to write to that file the complete thing and then You can use that html (works well tho only for those values only, not easy to implement to show more on a website than those numbers)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to describe this solution but it is a solution nonetheless:

```py
import os

lst = [
    577.007, 9.687, 535.798, 31.522, 545.485
]

p = ''
for num in lst:
    p += f'<p>{num}</p>\n'

html = f"""

<!doctype>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
{p}
</body>
</html>

"""

with open('web.html', 'w') as file:
    file.write(html)

os.startfile('web.html')
```

You don't have to necessarily use that `os.startfile` but You get the idea I hope, You now have `web.html` file and You can display it on Your website or whatever and theoretically You can also get a normal html document and copy it there (set as html variable and put the `{p}` wherever You need/want) or even go to Your html and put somewhere for example `{%%}` (which is what django uses but anyways),then read the whole file and replace those `{%%}` with Your value and write that back.

At the end this is a solution but depending on what You use e.g. a framework of sorts for example django or flask, there are easier ways to do that there